# Getting value of a Fluent UI dropdown without TypeScript in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

As you all know, in a normal dropdown, you can get the value of it onchange with `onChange={e => this.setState({ whatever: e.target.value })}`. The thing is, in Fluent UI React, this does not work, since it has a custom value handling system. In the Fluent UI docs it says to link the onChange function to:

```
const onChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>, item: IDropdownOption): void => {
    setSelectedItem(item);
  };
```

My project has to be TypeScript free because it is integrating with another application in a special way. Is there any way to get the value of this dropdown onChange rather than use Typescript?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can just provide a plain js function `(event, value) => {./* Do what you want */ }`

Comment: If I console.log the value of value and event after creating a plain js function both value and event are ```[object Object]```. Is this normal? How would I pass the props to the function? ```onChange={this.onChange}``` is how I am getting to the JS function. Is this wrong? @known-as-bmf

Comment: Sike i played with it some more and you got it @known-as-bmf! Thanks bro! (That was a genderless bro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the callback function on onChange of the Dropdown and pass event and option as two argument to the callback.

For Example

```
onChange = (event, option) => {
}
```